# Get specific content from a web service response in PHP

Tags: php, xml, web-services

I need to create a PHP page to display the content of a webservice in a certain way. Here is an example of the webservice that I get:

```
<srt:searchResult service="CONSULTA_CENS">
<parameterSet>
<parameter itemNum="1" name="numDocument" value="38794083Y"/>
</parameterSet>
<resultSet>
<result itemNum="1" id="name" dataType="STRING" name="Name">Peter</result>
<result itemNum="2" id="surname" dataType="STRING" name="Surname">Kepler</result>
<result itemNum="3" id="dir" dataType="STRING" name="Adress">Fake Street 123</result>
<result itemNum="4" id="district" dataType="STRING" name="District Code">05</result>
</resultSet>
<messageSet/>
</srt:searchResult>
```

And what I need to echo on the PHP script is the "name" and the "value" of each "result" on a different line, something like:

- Name: Peter
- Surname: Kepler
- Adress: Fake Street 123
- District Code: 05

What should I do after I call the XML?

```
  $xml = simplexml_load_file("XML_URL");
  //...?
```

Comment: `What should I do after i call the XML?` Iterate over the XML object and extract the desired properties

Comment: check this : https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_read.asp
you have to parse the xml and get the elements into array.